Adjusting size of operations in quantikz
I am trying to adjust the relative size between gate boxes and simpler gate operations (e.g. CNOTs), but am having some trouble. The main motivation is to draw a large circuit, in which case the CNOT controls and targets become quite small, so it would be nice to enlarge them.
A minimal example is as follows:
\documentclass[border=2px]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
\inputD[style={fill=red!20}]{\ket{+}} & \ctrl{1}\\
\ket{0} & \targ\\
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}

I would like to increase the size of the \ctrl black dot for CNOT and \targ symbol, without changing the rest. What would be the best way to do so?

Are you looking for \targ[style={scale=2}]?

Yes, thank you!

In addition to styling symbols individually, as suggested in the comments, you can apply global styles to subsets of symbols. For example,
\tikzset{phase/.append style={scale=2},circlewc/.append style={scale=2}}
\begin{quantikz}
\inputD[style={fill=red!20}]{\ket{+}} & \ctrl{1}\\
\ket{0} & \targ\\
\end{quantikz}

This works because \ket is not in the same group as either \ctrl or \targ, but obviously it depends on the range of symbols you're using altogether. At the same time, it probably makes sense to use these global groupings in all but strange cases because the subsets combine similar symbols, so you'd want uniform scaling for reasons of consistency anyway, and using the global subset styles makes it easier to ensure that consistency.
Page 17 of the manual explains the subsets of symbols to which the various styles apply. Page 18 explains how to customise the style of individual elements.
\begin{quantikz}
  \inputD[style={fill=red!20}]{\ket{+}} & \ctrl[style={scale=1.5}]{1}\\
  \ket{0} & \targ[style={scale=1.5}]\\
\end{quantikz}

Complete code:
\documentclass[border=2px]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}
  \inputD[style={fill=red!20}]{\ket{+}} & \ctrl[style={scale=1.5}]{1}\\
  \ket{0} & \targ[style={scale=1.5}]\\
\end{quantikz}
\tikzset{phase/.append style={scale=2},circlewc/.append style={scale=2}}
\begin{quantikz}
\inputD[style={fill=red!20}]{\ket{+}} & \ctrl{1}\\
\ket{0} & \targ\\
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}

Apologies for the lack of images. Okular-on-X currently has a bug affecting image quality horribly.

If you want, you can try my script to generate an image from a latex file without screenshot (it runs a combination of latexmk, pdftoppm and convert).

@jlab Actually, I'd not thought about pdftoppm. Thanks. It wouldn't work for everything, but it ought to work for images. (Although my editor is supposed to be using convert. But I'm not sure I believe it.) Thanks very much!
